# Simple incremental string replace in php

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace

I have the folowing code:

```
<?php
$subject = "Replace ? question mark in brackets [? with ? incremental ??]? digits";
echo incremental_replace($subject);
// i want the folowing: 
// Replace ? question mark in brackets [1 with 2 incremental 34]? digits
```

I want all the `?` in the brackets to be replaced. Also, the number and position of `?` can change.

How do i do that with php ? I think this can be done with preg_replace, but i don't know how.

Comment: How would you know which question marks to replace and which to leave alone?

Comment: look on this http://ideone.com/B8i4o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if brackets are not nested, then the following would be enough

```
echo preg_replace('~\?(?=[^\[\]]*\])~e', '++$n', $subject);
```

otherwise use a parser:

```
$subject = "Replace ? question mark in [nested ? brackets] [? with ? [incremental ? [?]] ??]? digits";
$result = '';

$bc = $n = 0;
foreach(str_split($subject) as $c) {
    if($c == '[') $bc++;
    if($c == ']') $bc--;
    if($c == '?' && $bc) $c = ++$n;
    $result .= $c;
}

echo $result;
```

A regular expression for nested brackets is possible but will be too long and messed up.

---

**Note by OP**: If the replacements are not incremental digits but an array, you can do the folowing:

```
$n = 0;
$rep = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'quux');
echo preg_replace('~\?(?=[^\[\]]*\])~e', '$rep[$n++]', $subject);
```

Comment: Where can i find documentation about the `'++$n'` ?

Comment: See [pattern modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). So you can do `$n = 42`; before `preg_replace` and i will replace with 43, 44 and so on...

Answer (score 2):

### Correct solution to the problem

```
function incremental_replace($subject) {
    $replacer = function($matches) {
        $index = 0;
        return preg_replace('/\?/e', '++$index', $matches[0]);
    };
    return preg_replace_callback('/\[[^\]]*\]/', $replacer, $subject);
}

$subject = "Replace ? question mark in brackets [? with ? incre?mental ??]?...";
echo incremental_replace($subject);
```

### Previous form of this answer

*I had misunderstood the question, and answered another similar question instead. I 'm leaving the answer here because someone might find it useful.*

The general idea is this:

```
function replacer($matches) {
    $replacements = array(1, 2, 34);
    $index = 0;
    return preg_replace('/\?+/e', '$replacements[$index++]', $matches[0]);
}

$subject = "Replace ? question mark in brackets [? with ? incremental ??]?...";
echo preg_replace_callback('/\[[^\]]*\]/', 'replacer', $subject);
```

**[See the basic concept in action](http://www.ideone.com/jcZ4b)**.

If you are using PHP >= 5.3, you can then do a much more generalized solution:

```
function incremental_replace($subject, $replacements) {
    $replacer = function($matches) use ($replacements) {
        $index = 0;
        return preg_replace('/\?+/e', '$replacements[$index++]', $matches[0]);
    };
    return preg_replace_callback('/\[[^\]]*\]/', $replacer, $subject);
}


$subject = "Replace ? question mark in brackets [? with ? incremental ??]?...";
echo incremental_replace($subject, array(1, 2, 34));
```

Finally, if you are willing to limit yourself to *only single question marks* (i.e. if the `??` inside the brackets can be changed to simply `?`) then you can swap the `preg_replace` inside the "replacer" function with a simple `str_replace`, which would be faster.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not willing to change the `$subject`

Comment: @pinouchon: I just realized I had answered a slightly different question instead of the one you asked. Please take a look at the new update.

Comment: @stereofrog `Warning: vsprintf(): Too few arguments`. Good point.

Comment: @stereofrog: Depends on whether you 'd prefer a shorter or a faster solution. Is there anything else wrong with this mess?

Comment: @stereofrog: Corrected the solution for this case, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @pinouchon: Corrected the solution.

Answer (score 1):

A simple parser can do the job. It's just a simple solution with room for improvement. But perhaps [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) or [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) might be more efficient in this case.

```
function incremental_replace($subject) {
    $inBracket  = 0;
    $length = strlen($subject);
    $count      = 0;
    $result = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $char = $subject[$i];
        switch ($char) {
            case '[':
                $inBracket++;
                break;
            case ']':
                $inBracket--;
                break;
            case '?':
                if ($inBracket > 0) {
                    $char = ++$count;
                }
                break;
        }
        $result .= $char;
    }
    return $result;
}

$subject = "Replace ? question mark in brackets [? with ? incremental ??]? digits";
echo incremental_replace($subject);
// Replace ? question mark in brackets [1 with 2 incremental 34]? digits
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function replaceThem($matches){
    $i = 1;
    while ($pos = strpos($matches[0], '?'))
        $matches[0][$pos] = $i++;
    return $matches[0];
}
$subject = "Replace ? question mark in brackets [? with ? incremental ??]? digits";
echo preg_replace_callback('/\[[^\]]+\]/', 'replaceThem', $subject);
```

http://www.ideone.com/kBnMK

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's best to loop through the characters of the string. If you pass the opening bracket, replace the question marks you encounter with the counter, same for the second, etc. and if you pass the closing bracket...stop replacing.

Comment: I tought about that, but I don't like it. I'm sure there is a simple way with a php built'in function.

Comment: Well...there sure is a way, but I doubt it to be simple. My guess would be that you will end up using Regular Expressions than.